# Getting the wrong string from a ComboBox after executing the Sendmessage function

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm facing an issue with where I am getting the wrong string from a `ComboBox` after executing the `Sendmessage` function.
What do you think could be wrong here?

```
 hCombo = CreateWindow(L"COMBOBOX", L"combobox",
       WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_SORT | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL,
       10, 50, 250, 500, hWnd, (HMENU)0, hInstance, NULL);
   std::string text = "1 2 3 4 5 6";
   SendMessage(hCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)text.c_str());
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`c_str()` returns an ANSI string. To make it work, you need do like this:

```
SendMessageA(hCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)text.c_str());
```

Comment: Use `std::wstring text = L"text"` to avoid ANSI

Comment: `c_str() returns ANSI string`. No, it doesn't. `std::wstring::c_str` very much returns a wide string.

Comment: @MSalters the code is using `std::string`, so its `c_str()` *does* return a `char*` (ANSI) string.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the `LPARAM` cast hides your error. You are compiling with `UNICODE` enabled, so by default your strings should be wide (`wchar_t`) strings, which for string literals means prefixing them with `L`, ie `L"1 2 3 4 5 6"`.

Your compiler will now tell you that the type of the `text` variable is wrong. That needs to be changed to `std::wstring` for wide strings.